# tensorflow efficient way for tensor multiplication

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I have two tensors in tensorflow, the first tensor is 3-D, and the second is 2D. And I want to multiply them like this:

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[sequence_length, batch_size, hidden_num]) 
w = tf.get_variable("w", [hidden_num, 50]) 
b = tf.get_variable("b", [50])

output_list = []
for step_index in range(sequence_length):
    output = tf.matmul(x[step_index,  :,  :], w) + b
    output_list.append(output)
output = tf.pack(outputs_list)
```

I use a loop to do multiply operation, but I think it is too slow. What would be the best way to make this process as simple/clean as possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `batch_matmul`. Unfortunately it doesn't seem `batch_matmul` supports broadcasting along the batch dimension, so you have to tile your `w` matrix. This will use more memory, but all operations will stay in TensorFlow

```
a = tf.ones((5, 2, 3))
b = tf.ones((3, 1))
b = tf.reshape(b, (1, 3, 1))
b = tf.tile(b, [5, 1, 1])
c = tf.batch_matmul(a, b) # use tf.matmul in TF 1.0 
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
sess.run(tf.shape(c))
```

This gives

```
array([5, 2, 1], dtype=int32)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I have a question, after using tf.tile, the size of variable of b change, because there are some useless data in it. So it is difficult do calculate tf.nn.l2_loss(b)

Comment: Btw tile input can be a tensor, so you can construct shape arg dynamically from tf.shape(w)

Comment: In tensorflow 1.0, use `tf.matmul` instead of `tf.batch_matmul`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`map_fn`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/api_docs/python/functional_ops.html#map_fn), which scans a function along the first  dimension.

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[sequence_length, batch_size, hidden_num]) 
w = tf.get_variable("w", [hidden_num, 50]) 
b = tf.get_variable("b", [50])

def mul_fn(current_input):
    return tf.matmul(current_input, w) + b

output = tf.map_fn(mul_fn, x)
```

[I used this at one point](https://github.com/Sentimentron/Dracula/blob/tensorflow3/nn_layers.py#L90) to implement a softmax scan along a sequence.